# Beer is lacking in flavor

Tags: beer, coopers

I have just started to drink a batch of coopers Dark ale it has been bottled for two weeks now.
the carbonation looks ok a nice hiss when the bottle is opend. lots of bubbles in the glass and and lots of bubbles rising to the surface. but no head at all I used a dark enhancer as advised by coopers.
Also the beer does not tast like beer realy. it tastes like a soft drink the ABV was 4.2. I cant tast any hoppiness in the beer or many beer flavors at all. but what i can tast is very nice
Any ideas please

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to include the details of the recipe. Include all the ingredients, amounts, and timing/temperatures for when they were added.

Comment: Is it sweet? Yes, please show the recipe or I'll have to pull this question